# Url rewriting rule with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm here to ask for advice about the .htaccess file that I can't configure as I would like.

I have a site, let's say : 
**www.mysite.com/php/blog.php**

I would like the visitor to see in the address bar only:
**www.mysite.com/blog**

This is what the .htaccess file contains:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php     #This line is to hide index.php on the home page, maybe it's not the right way to do it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^php/([0-9a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1 [L]            #I tried to write this, but it doesn't work
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I suspect that this question has been asked many times, but I have really tried, without success.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your patter is wrongly expecting URI to start with `/php/` which is not the case here. Also keep `http -> https` rules at top and then handle `.php` extension rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# http -> https redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# To externally redirect /php/file.php to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:php/)?(\S+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally forward file to /php/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/php/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ php/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello anubhava, thanks for your time ! 

Nope, it don't works unfortunately. By the way, i'm looking to hide the folder's path /php/ in the adress bar, and also the .php extension.

I would like to obtain "www.mysite.com/contact" rather than "www.mysite.com/php/contact.php"